# C++ Compiling simple test with cmake using GCC and GTest fails while using clang works

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, clang

I'm trying to compile a simple test with cmake, GCC and Gtest which fails during linking.

This is my cmake file:

```
project("test")

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

include(${CMAKE_ROOT}/Modules/ExternalProject.cmake)

SET_DIRECTORY_PROPERTIES(PROPERTIES EP_PREFIX ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/third_party)

ExternalProject_Add(
        googletest_utilities
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/google/googletest
        GIT_TAG release-1.11.0
        CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}
        -DCMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG:PATH=DebugLibs
        -DCMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE:PATH=ReleaseLibs
        -Dgtest_force_shared_crt=ON
        INSTALL_COMMAND "")

# Specify include dir
ExternalProject_Get_Property(googletest_utilities source_dir)

include_directories(${source_dir}/googletest/include)
include_directories(${source_dir}/googlemock/include)

add_executable(main test.cpp)

add_dependencies(main googletest_utilities)

if (${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} STREQUAL "Debug")
        set(CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX d)
endif()

target_link_libraries(main
            general pthread
            general c++
            general ${source_dir}/../googletest_utilities-build/googletest/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}Libs/${CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES}gtest${CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX}.a
            general ${source_dir}/../googletest_utilities-build/googletest/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}Libs/${CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES}gtest_main${CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX}.a
            )
```

and my c++ file:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

TEST(Mytest, failing_test){
    EXPECT_TRUE(false);
}
 
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Using clang as my compiler it will compile and run but when i clean the build folder and change my compiler to GCC 11.2 it will fail with this linker error:

```
  "__ZN7testing8internal30GetBoolAssertionFailureMessageB5cxx11ERKNS_15AssertionResultEPKcS5_S5_", referenced from:
      __ZN24Mytest_failing_test_Test8TestBodyEv in test.cpp.o
```

Using a demangler for it will output:

```
_testing::internal::GetBoolAssertionFailureMessage[abi:cxx11](testing::AssertionResult const&, char const*, char const*, char const*)
```

while the generated gtest library will contain:

```
_testing::internal::GetBoolAssertionFailureMessage(testing::AssertionResult const&, char const*, char const*, char const*)
```

so i think the problem is connected to the abi but i can't figure it out how to solve it.

Comment: Why is there "general" before every library in `target_link_libraries`? You want to link 4 times with general? `but when i clean the build folder and change my compiler to GCC 11.2` What do you mean? Why weren't you using GCC11.2 from the start? Did you reconfigure and recompile your project? `include(${CMAKE_ROOT}/Modules/` is odd, just `include(ExternalProjectAdd)`. And googletest is in CMake, did you follow https://google.github.io/googletest/quickstart-cmake.html ?

Comment: General is a keyword( The general keyword corresponds to all configurations, and is purely optional.)
By cleaning the build folder i mean if i try to switch between compilers, like first testing clang like this:
`cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/clang++ -Bbuild/ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug`
and then deleting the build folder and switch to GCC
`cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/local/bin/gcc-11 -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/local/bin/g++-11 -Bbuild/ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug`

Comment: And using ExternalProject_Add or FetchContent_Declare like in GTest example should be the same

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out. The problem was that ExternalProject_Add will not respect the CMAKE_C_COMPILER and CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER variables, so when it was building the google test project it was using the default compilers which on my machine it's clang while the main project it was build with GCC.
The solution was to pass the CMAKE_C_COMPILER and CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER into CMAKE_ARGS like this

```
CMAKE_ARGS
            -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}
            -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=${CMAKE_C_COMPILER})
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).